# Drawing path in Project tango augmented reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, android-augmented-reality

Explored Augmented reality using project-tango, which locates the 3D objects exactly in a particular position in the real world. While navigating to that object or nearing that object a pathway should be overlaid to that object as shown in the image below
[image]

This arrow spreads on the floor(using depth) while walking with the device. Project tango has some 3D Models which extends Object3D. I don't think those models will help to do this. Is there any way or library to get it drawn?

Comment: Can you load an obj or fbx file? It sounds like you are using Java, some of the Tango examples use Java rajawalli render library, it has a decent mesh loading function.

Comment: Now the problem is not drawing path, but getting the relevant ground level depth points to draw path to a place marked in the adf

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but answering for any future visitors (:

There are now examples for [ExperimentalFloorFinding](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/ExperimentalFloorFinding) which shows you how to get the floor position from the point cloud data.
Combined with Jasons suggestion for loading .obj, or with calling Instantiate() on a prefab, you should be able to find the position and draw the object.